# Iterating over a list of objects c++

Tags: c++, list, class, object, listiterator

Basically I am creating a basic shell program for a class project. I am stuck on iterating through the files/folders within a directory.

My error is in the function DisplayDirectoryContents()

```
class Directory 
{
private:
map<string, pair<list<Folder>, list<File> > > directoryContents;
string directoryPath;

public:
list<Folder> getFolders() {return directoryContents[directoryPath].first;}
list<File> getFiles() {return directoryContents[directoryPath].second;}
string getDirectoryPath() {return directoryPath;}

Directory() 
{
    directoryPath = "root/"; 
    File *file = new File("Test");
    directoryContents[directoryPath].second.push_back(*file);
}
void DisplayDirectoryContents()
{
    // Get files and folders from directory
    list<File> files = this->getFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << files->getFileName(); << Error here
    }

}
};
```

I've tried setting this function up a few different ways but I can't seem to get the right kind of code to make it work.

I would think this would work but it's throwing me errors everytime I try and mess with the DisplayDirectoryContents() function. Does anyone have any tips that I can try to help fix this? Thanks

```
class File
{
string fileName;
string fileTime;
public:
string getFileTime(){return fileTime;}
string getFileName(){return fileName;}

void setFileTime(){time_t now = time(NULL);
                fileTime = ctime(&now);} 
void setFileName(string newFileName){fileName = newFileName;}
File(){}
File(string fName)
{
    fileName = fName;
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    fileTime = ctime(&now);
}
void MakeFile(string fName);
void RemoveFile(string fName); 
};
```

Comment: The map in your design just looks obsolete - instead of that map with just one single entry, just have two simple list members.

Comment: I do not see any definition for `Folder` - did you intend `std::list<Directory>` instead (would make sense at least...)?

Comment: So, the reason I used the map is because I am going to make it so you can add a lot more directories, files and folders. Should I still use it for that or switch to simple list members?

Comment: And yeah I was just testing to make sure it worked with the file before I moved onto the folder class

Comment: You can add arbitrary number of files or folders to the lists already. The map *only* is meaningful if you want to add entries for more than one different directory path. `Directory` and `Folder` will get two different classes for the same thing. Nothing speaks against adding other `Directory` instances to the parent `Directory` instance. Wouldn't this better reflect file systems as well?

Comment: Side note: In general, I recommend *not* storing file time as string - both [linux](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stat) and [windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-getfileinformationbyhandle) give you file time as numeric value, so you might prefer storing it as such, you can work with much easier and you'd only convert it to string when printing to console (or showing in a GUI element). Specific exception: If you don't ever use the value for anything else than displaying, *then* you might keep the string for not having to re-create it every time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to use C++11 or higher, you can use a range `for` loop to iterate over the contents of the list.

```
void DisplayDirectoryContents()
{
    // Get files and folders from directory
    list<File> files = this->getFiles();

    // Iterate over each item in the list.
    // Use a reference to avoid copying of the items.
    for ( File& file : files )
    {
        cout << file.getFileName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Yeah I am able to use it, and this worked! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Extension to [R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196547/1312382):

The reason you cannot iterate using your original loop is because `std::list` does not offer an index operator (you would need to use `std::vector` instead).

Alternative approach to the range based for loop (which I'd prefer, though, unless you have specific reasons not to do so) – or the way to go if you have no C++11 available – is using iterators:

```
for(std::list<File>::iterator i = files.begin(); i != files.end(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << i->getFileName();
}
```

With C++11, you can have `for(auto i = files.begin(); ...`.

Use cases for using iterator loop even with C++11 can be comparing items with their successors:

```
// check for empty list first, as std::prev would fail on!)
for(auto i = files.begin(); i != std::prev(files.end()); ++i)
{
    if(someCondition(*i, *std::next(i))
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

There is already [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) for and you should prefer it (together with a lambda;  but don't forget to apply [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) afterwards, see [erase-remove-idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)!), so just for illustration; starting with the simpler approach:

```
for(auto i = files.begin(); i != files.end(); ) // no ++i (!)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        i = files.erase(i);
        // fine for std::list; with std::vector, if removing more
        // than one single element, we'd move or even copy subsequent
        // elements multiple times, which is quite inefficient
    }
}
```

Improved variant (which is what `std::remove_if` does as well):

```
auto pos = files.begin();
for(auto i = files.begin(); i != files.end(); ++i)
{
    if(!condition)
    // ^ (!)
    {
        *pos++ = std::move(*i);
    }
}
// here, std::remove_if already stops, but returns pos...
files.erase(pos, files.end());
```

A minimal problem might remain with move or copy assignment operators not handling self-assignment correctly, which would be covered by `if(!condition && i != pos)`.